# How to create a package in EPIServer to make it deployable in client side

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

I have written a code in EPIServer for creating a pagetype from code . Now I want to deploy it in client side with the help of package like things. For this the client prefer .episerverdata file . Now my question is that how to build that file and how to use that file in the client side.

Please help I am very new in this EPIServer world.

Thanks

Utpal Maity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is using PageTypeBuilder you just deploy your project's DLL. The new page type will then be automatically added.

Otherwise import and export (of .episerverdata files) is done from Admin mode.